# manage.py error after Wagtail 2.15 upgrade

Tags: django, wagtail, wagtail-search

After upgrading to Wagtail 2.15 (or 2.15.1) from 2.14.2 my production website with postgres and database search breaks and commands that are run with `manage.py` give an error despite me adding the required `WAGTAILSEARCH_BACKENDS` to settings.

I have two web apps with separate settings running from the same Wagtail version. One of the apps (putkeep) has a search bar and the other (secretgifter) does not. After upgrading Wagtail from 2.14.2 to 2.15, putkeep gives a 404 error but secretgifter does not. If I use pip to switch back to 2.14.2, then the 404 error goes away and the site loads (although results from a search give a 500 error).

If I run `makemigrations` (or any other command that uses `manage.py`) for secretgifter it works fine. For putkeep (with the search) it gives the following error:

```
  File "manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/home/th-putkeep.net/putkeep/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 419, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/home/th-putkeep.net/putkeep/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 395, in execute
    django.setup()
  File "/home/th-putkeep.net/putkeep/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 24, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "/home/th-putkeep.net/putkeep/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 122, in populate
    app_config.ready()
  File "/home/th-putkeep.net/putkeep/lib/python3.8/site-packages/wagtail/search/apps.py", line 21, in ready
    set_weights()
  File "/home/th-putkeep.net/putkeep/lib/python3.8/site-packages/wagtail/search/backends/database/postgres/weights.py", line 44, in set_weights
    BOOSTS_WEIGHTS.extend(determine_boosts_weights())
  File "/home/th-putkeep.net/putkeep/lib/python3.8/site-packages/wagtail/search/backends/database/postgres/weights.py", line 32, in determine_boosts_weights
    boosts = get_boosts()
  File "/home/th-putkeep.net/putkeep/lib/python3.8/site-packages/wagtail/search/backends/database/postgres/weights.py", line 26, in get_boosts
    boosts.add(boost)
TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'
```

As per the docs I've added this to my settings:

```
WAGTAILSEARCH_BACKENDS = {
    'default': {
        'BACKEND': 'wagtail.search.backends.database',
    }
}
```

Any suggestions gratefully received.

Comment: Well that's mildly embarrassing... Thank you for proofing and correcting Dan 

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have identified some code in my `models.py` that caused no errors with my site running Wagtail 2.14.2 and below. When commented out, it resolves the error caused by upgrading to Wagtail 2.15 and above. I am posting it here as the answer to my problem because everything else seems to work (including search) without any further modification even though I am not currently sure why it causes the error or if I need it anymore:

```
    search_fields = Page.search_fields + [  # Inherit search_fields from Page
        index.SearchField('content'),
        index.SearchField('tags', [
            index.SearchField('name', partial_match=True, boost=10),
        ]),
    ]
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is with your configuration that is trying to search tag names:

```
index.SearchField('tags', [
    index.SearchField('name', partial_match=True, boost=10),
]),
```

The default database search doesn't appear to offer an option to search related objects this way (See note under https://docs.wagtail.io/en/stable/topics/search/indexing.html#indexing-callables-and-other-attributes). You can either remove those lines or, for the moment, go back to the postgres_search backend in wagtail/contrib.